# String.trim() removes not only spaces in Java

Tags: java, string, trim

String.trim() in java removes all characters whose ascii value is less than or equal to 20 (space).

Any idea why Java did that instead of removing only space (ascii char 20)

```
public String trim() {
    int len = count;
    int st = 0;
    int off = offset;      /* avoid getfield opcode */
    char[] val = value;    /* avoid getfield opcode */

    while ((st < len) && (val[off + st] <= ' ')) {
        st++;
    }
    while ((st < len) && (val[off + len - 1] <= ' ')) {
         len--;
    }
    return ((st > 0) || (len < count)) ? substring(st, len) : this;
}
```

Comment: it removes *whitespaces* which also includes many other characters such as `carriage return` or `line break` and so on

Comment: It returns a copy of this string with leading and trailing white space removed, or this string if it has no leading or trailing white space. So your first statement is wrong.

Comment: Space is ASCII character code 32, not 20.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character

Comment: 20 hex = 32 dec

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback. And welcome to "upvote" privilege ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because there are many different ways of having *empty* space, besides that " " space character. Quoting the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()):

> Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

The javadoc is clear here: it is not about **space** but **white space**. Things that would show up as "empty" - but that are in fact **different** from plain " " empty strings.

In other words: this is a convenience method. Such methods are designed to provide that functionality that users do need/expect.

It would be absolutely counter-intuition to provide a `trim()` method that only works spaces.

A very typical scenario is: you receive some string. It could be entered by a user, it could be read from a file and represent a whole line. You are not interested in any trailing tabs, spaces, new line characters. Thus the fathers of the Java language give you a method to get rid of all these different characters easily. Instead of you calling `trimSpaces()`, `trimTabs()`, `trimNewLines()`, etc. pp.

Comment: I was about to post something similar using the term "not visible character" but this works too!

Comment: "white space" has common meaning since 1970

Comment: @davidxxx Thank you very much. I didn't make 80 points on a single answer since ages it feels ...

Answer (score 1):

The ASCII character code for space is actually 32, not 20.  But if you look at the sorts of characters which come before 32 you will find many types of whitespace, such as tab and carriage return.  The asssumption is the average user would want to strip all such whitespace surrounding a string.

To round out the answer given by @GhostCat here is a one-liner you can use to selectively trim only space:

```
String input = "   Hello World!   ";
input = input.replaceAll("[ ]*(.*)[ ]*", "$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

The below one-liner works. The one given by @Tim Biegeleisen doesn't remove a trailing space.

```
 String input = "   Hello World!   ";
 input = input.replaceFirst("^\\s++", "").replaceFirst("\\s++$","");
```